# Poll that allows users to add options, but not see results

Tags: web-apps, java, survey

I need an online poll service that allows users to add their own options. I know someone made one on here, but I need the results to remain secret and not shown to voters.

I need it to:

- create the poll by choosing a number of preset options
- have a URL of the poll to send to potential voters
- the voters can select one, possibly many, options and submit their vote
- if desired, voters can add their own option and vote for that
- voters cannot see results

Comment: 1. You added the [tag:java] tag. Does that mean the application has to be written in Java? 2. Do you need a hosted or a self-hosted solution? 3. What’s your budget? Or does it have to be gratis?

Comment: Can voters see the new options created by previous voters?

Comment: 1. Doesn't have to be java 2. Gratis 3. Yes, users can see the new options

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with https://pollunit.com and an premium account.

With a private PollUnit the participants can not see the votes of the other participants. The result is only visible when the PollUnit is closed. The creator can see the result at any time.

If you never close the poll, the votes remain hidden.

**Disclosure:** I am one of the developers.